# Why Google asks for "Title" for MIME type "image/*" in Google Webmasters?

Tags: google-search-console

In my Google Webmasters account, in **Optimization** section, under **HTML improvements** I see that Google has indexed more than 100 links complaining that these links has no **Title** associated with them (*Missing title tags*).

However, these links all result in thumbnails of images and they are served as MIME type (Internet Media Type) of "image/png", or "image/jpg", etc.

What's wrong here? How should I tell Google that an image can't have a title tag?

Note: An example link can be see [here](http://nefkanto.ir/generate-a-thumbnail-of-size/700xauto/for-image-number/2352).

Comment: I assume you mean Google Webmaster Tools rather than Google Analytics? Anyway this seems like a bug with GWT.

Comment: Yep, sorry @DisgruntledGoat. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok, webmaster tool is still buggy with Mime type file.
(I've got the same problem)

It should be corrected soon.

Comment: I think I'm fine with treating this as a *Google's bug* rather than a technical misunderstanding of mine ;).